# Django queryset permissions

Tags: python, django

I am building a quite complex `Django` application to be used on top of and email scanning service. The `Django` application is written using Python 3.5+

This application primarily uses `Django Rest Framework` to handle communication with the frontend in the browser.

The issue that I am currently having is that I try to implement the concept of a `System Administrator`, `Domain Administrator` and `Application User`

The `System Administrator` is basically the "normal" django `superuser` and is therefore capable of doing everything and see every record in the system.

The `Domain Administrator` is user who manages one or more `email domains`. I keep track of this using a `Many2Many` relationship between the `users` and the `domains`. The idea would then be to predefine a filter, so that the log of messages processed, will be automatically filtered to show only messages where the `sender domain` or the `recipient domain` equal a `domain` in the list of `domains` that the given `user` is assigned to.

The same would be true for `blacklisting`/`whitelisting` policies.

If the `Domain Administrator` is not assigned to any `domains`, then no data is shown.

The `Application User` is basically any authenticated user with one or more `domains` assigned to them, using the same `Many2Many` relationship as the `Domain Administrator`. If no domains are assigned, then no data is shown.

I have found some other solution here on Stackoverflow on making the `request.user` available to the `QuerySet` in the `ModelManager`, but that does not seem like the correct way to handle it.

I have looked at `django-guardian`, `django-authority` and `django-permissions`, but none of them seem to be affecting the `QuerySet` or the resulting list of objects.

Does anyone have a suggestion for Django package/addon that can be used to handle this or maybe an idea for how this could be handled?

Comment: Can't the deal with it in the view?

Comment: If it can be done inside a `ViewSet`, then yes. The entire `API` is using `ViewSets`. A `Permission` class would normally be an option, but according to the documentation, it does not modify the queryset or the results

Comment: Why not override `get_queryset`? Do you want to avoid writing custom `get_queryset` for each of these roles and have something generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRF's `GenericAPIView` has a `get_queryset` method that you can override to perform custom filtering:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(YourView, self).get_queryset()
    return self.filter_queryset_for_user(qs, request.user)


def filter_queryset_for_user(self, qs, user):
    pass  # Your logic here
```

This is not necessarily a bad idea; DRF docstrings recommend overriding this:

> You may want to override this if you need to provide different
>           querysets depending on the incoming request.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I will need to do some testing, as I have some reporting functionality that allows the user to filter the data of certain tables based on parameters like the sender and recipient.

Comment: As one of the comment mentions, this is more of a filtering problem than a permissions problem. Lmk if the solution I proposed is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of `django-cancan` library https://github.com/pgorecki/django-cancan which strives to solve the exact problem you are describing.

The philosophy is as following: first, you determine per-user abilities, then in a view, you can check user abilities for a given object, model, or you can retrieve a queryset based on those abilities.

The declaration part looks like this:

```py
def declare_abilities(user, ability):
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        # Allow anonymous users to view only published articles
        ability.can('view', Article, published=True)
    else:
        # logged in user can view any article...
        ability.can('view', Article)
        # ... and change his own
        ability.can('change', Article, author=user)
        # ... and add new ones
        ability.can('add', Article)

    if user.is_superuser:
        # Allow superuser to view and change any article
        ability.can('view', Article)
        ability.can('change', Article)
```

Then you can you can check for abilites on a per-object level:

```py
def article_detail_view(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.ability.can('view', article):
        ...
```

or on a model level:

```py
def article_create_view(request, pk):
    if request.ability.can('add', Article):
        ...
```

or get a queryset with accessible objects:

```py
def another_list_view(request, pk):
    articles = request.ability.queryset_for('view', Article)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of permission in Django. `django-guardian`, `django-authority` and `django-permissions` these all packages are for handling permission inside your Django application. What `permission` does is it checks certain model or instance of model, if the user has permission to view that particular model or object, otherwise it will return `403 Unauthorized` response. Permission does not change or filter your queryset to return only the valid results.

Rather if you want to apply filter your queryset, you can do so by the above answer, or you can move that code to a `Mixin` to follow `DRY Style`. For Mixin Reference you can see this link:

- https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2015/06/03/10-mixins.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0513I6_f2Tc

Answer (score 0):

[My answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610589/9853105) also provides an alternative to filter your queryset by subclassing `rest_framework.filters.BaseFilterBackend` and implement `filter_queryset()` based on your permission pattern , which would be suitable for  more complicated use cases.